# MySQL choosing the grouping by

Tags: mysql

```
'select d.*, b.date AS thestart_date
        from deals d
        join deals_bookings b on d.id = b.deal_id
        where b.date > curdate()
          and b.deal_id not in (
            select deal_id
            from deals_bookings
            where date <= curdate()
        )
        and b.display_upcoming = 1
        GROUP BY b.deal_id
        order by b.date asc'
```

How can i be GROUPing by the b.date ASC, so the one row it picks per. deal_id, is the one with the closest date (which you can get by "order by b.date asc limit 1" in normal circumstances.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregate [MIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) function to choose the appropriate date.

```
select d.*, MIN(b.date) AS thestart_date
...
```